# JSOM: Fastest way to get count of list items in a view

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, list-view, jsom

My current JavaScript implementation is based on answer in

[How to get all items in a View using Client Object Model (JavaScript)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28446/how-to-get-all-items-in-a-view-using-client-object-model-javascript).

Is there a way to avoid loading the view first? Also, I am not interested in data (not event the Ids of items), just need the count.

Comment: Where do you need that? In the `ViewPage.aspx`? what is the SharePoint version?

Answer (score 2):

If environment is SP 2013 and it is needed to count total items in any view pages like `AllItems.aspx`, then the fastest way is following

```
ctx.ListData.Row.length
```

It will return totals items in this view.

*Regarding [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28446/how-to-get-all-items-in-a-view-using-client-object-model-javascript) answer*

It is the optimum way to get total items in a view I guess. Following is the process to get items from view

- Need the CAML query from the view
- Using this CAML query all items can be retrieved

So minimum request is mandatory.

*If the CAML query of this view is already know to you, then you can retrieve all items by single request.*

Comment: Thanks. I need this in an App targeted for SP Online. I have the name of list and one or more views of that list and need to get count of items in each of those views.

Comment: Just remember to add `context.load(view, "ViewQuery");` and `context.load(items, "Include(ID)");` to the code from the answer. Then you have the count at `items.get_data().length` , still could take 4-5secs on a view with 5000 ish items

Comment: @AndersAune, thanks for the tip, if you put it as a separate answer I will accept it. I guess that's the best optimization we can have for the scenario.

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple of possibilities, looking at properties of the list rather than all the contents:
http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-development/using-splist-itemcount-vs-splist-items-count

Comment: And also this is not answering the question.question is regarding a way in JSOM.not server obj mdoel